# Count only first unique combination in grouped query

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a table that looks like this

```
| date       | user_id | event_id | message_id |
|------------|---------|----------|------------|
| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 1        | 1          |
| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 1        | 2          |
| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 2        | 3          |
| 2021-08-04 | 2       | 1        | 4          |
| 2021-08-05 | 1       | 1        | 1          |
| 2021-08-05 | 2       | 2        | 5          |
```

I want to group everything by user_id, date and event. But here is the question: I want to count unique combinations of (date-user-event-message) and only add it to the date row, where it occures first. In other words, if I have the same message_id, same user_id and same event_id but different date, I want to count it just once and add to the date-user-event row when this message occured first. So this is what I want to get:

```
| date       | user_id | event_id | count | count_unique |
|------------|---------|----------|-------|--------------|
| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 1        | 2     | 2            | <--- Unique count is 2 because this is the first date when two unique combinations of user+event+message found
| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 2        | 1     | 1            |
| 2021-08-04 | 2       | 1        | 1     | 1            |
| 2021-08-05 | 1       | 1        | 1     | 0            | <--- Unique count is 0, because this message_id for the same user and event already exists for previous date
| 2021-08-05 | 2       | 2        | 1     | 1            |
```

It's a bit tricky, and I'm pretty comfindent it's impossible, but I still need to be sure.

I came up with this query:

```
SELECT
    date,
    user_id,
    event_id,
    COUNT(*) as count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT message_id) as count_unique
FROM events
GROUP BY user_id, event_id, date
```

But the result I'm getting is obviously not what I'm aiming for:

```
| date       | user_id | event_id | count | count_unique |
|------------|---------|----------|-------|--------------|
| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 1        | 2     | 2            |
| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 2        | 1     | 1            |
| 2021-08-04 | 2       | 1        | 1     | 1            |
| 2021-08-05 | 1       | 1        | 1     | 1            | <--- Unique count is 1, because it counts distinct message_ids within the group (row).
| 2021-08-05 | 2       | 2        | 1     | 1            |
```

So basiclly I need to somehow ignore date for count distinct (e.g. count outside the group), and sum the count value only for the rows (groups) where date is the date where this combination found first.

Comment: for the first line `| 2021-08-04 | 1       | 1        | 2     | 1            |` the count_unique must 2 ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 yes, sorry, you are right. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute `count_unique` you want to keep only the first time a message that  is send by a user for a event .

For having this dataset you must execute this query .

```
select min(a_date) as date ,userid,event_id,message_id 
    from events 
    group by userid , event_id , message_id
```

So after this is easy to compute the value `count_unique`

```
select count(*) as count_unique , date , userid , event_id 
    from ( 
       select min(date) as date ,userid,event_id,message_id 
       from events
          group by userid , event_id , message_id ) e 
 group by date , userid , event_id ;
```

So now you can a left join with a query that count message by userid ,eventid, and date

```
select a.*,coalesce(b.count_unique,0) as count_unique 
   from ( 
     select date , userid , event_id , count(*) as cnt  from events 
     group by date , userid , event_id 
  ) a left join (
    select count(*) as count_unique , date , userid , event_id 
       from ( 
          select min(date) as date ,userid,event_id,message_id 
          from events
             group by userid , event_id , message_id ) e 
       group by date , userid , event_id 
  ) b on a.date=b.date and
        a.userid=b.userid and
        a.event_id = b.event_id;
```

Comment: Yup, looks like it. I didn’t think about using subquery with join. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This query will filter for those user_id/event_id/message_id combinations the first date they occur (using row_number window function) - and then aggregate on filtered set:

```
select 
   date
  , user_id
  , event_id
  , count(distinct message_id) as count_messages
from
(
select distinct date
  , user_id
  , event_id
  , message_id
  , row_number() over 
    (
      partition by user_id,event_id,message_id 
      order by date asc
    ) as rank_date
from events
) as DT
where rank_date = 1
```

In other words - this should only count user_id/event_id/message_id combinations the first date they occur.